# SQLITE3: Constant time row addressing

Tags: sqlite, pointers, indexing, graph-databases

Is it possible to access a row in an `sqlite3` table by ID in a constant time `jump` operation instead of what I assume is `O(n log n)` index search?

Given a table where each row holds one 'object' and its `id` is one of a consecutive list of ids, it would be possible in theory to jump to the row with the respective `id` in constant time. This amounts to storing row `pointers` in a table.

Does `sqlite` alow this and by which means?

**EDIT:** The database would not be loaded in memory and I am unsure if a pointer is possible on disk.

Comment: You might look into Berkeley DB. Oracle makes it as hard as possible to actually find decent documentation about it, but IIRC it has a database mode that supports fixed-length records (RECNO).

Comment: Don't get why you think your Q from today ~"works from cmd line but not as a shell script" . Post a new Q and add a comment with my @shellter so I can take a look at it. Include sample input (or SQL statements), exected output, your code, any error messages (exact text please). Good luck!

Comment: @shellter I am sorry about the confusion I started with that Q you are referring to. I removed it because there was typo that caused the problem. If you think this is a good idea, I can try and find a way to make my final code available, i.e. by answering my own question...

Comment: I had the typo both on the command line and in the script. Then I fixed the typo on the command line and it worked on the command line but not on the script. Then I thought it works only on the command line. Then I realized I had the same typo in the script, fixed it and it worked...

Comment: Great, glad you solved it. Good luck in your endeavors!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not possible with current implementation.

The page [Architecture of SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/arch.html) explains that

> A separate B-tree is used for each table and index in the database.

Various other pages mention the use of B-tree indexes.

The [Optimizer overview](https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html) page also makes no mention of a direct "pointer" index implementation.  Rather it only mentions the selection of appropriate indexes based on elements of an SQL query, but all such indexes would still be the standard b-tree requiring non-constant lookup time.

---

Honestly, I think the idea is good one for a table that is identified to only ever be accessed by a consecutive integer primary key (with very infrequent inserts and very few or no deletions), then a direct file pointer could be used to access the data as you describe.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering if they make a special implementation for example for `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` as this should insure all the requirements are met.

Comment: `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` alone does *not* ensure an optimized index in all cases.  Such a primary key still allows many inserts at random intervals and inserts of data in other tables between.  It also allows deletions of rows without any restrictions.  The resultant index could have many missing values and it would need to be constantly rewritten to the file and/or reserve a large, continuous block within the file. Those processes will add overhead and ultimately require much wasted space for the missing values (could not be excluded from such an index) and the continuous block.

Comment: If sqlite allowed the specification of such an index (perhaps something like `CONTIGUOUS INDEX`), it would either need to impose certain conditions on inserts and/or deletions OR it could leave those details up to the user and let them shoot themselves in the foot.  As an advanced user I prefer the later, but I'm certain that it would inevitably lead to confusion and misapplication.